# How to export docker process results to a local file - while connecting to the host through ssh?

Tags: docker, ssh

Well considering I have a docker (with postgres) running I could dump the data using `pg_dump` using:

```
sudo docker exec <DOCKERNAME> pg_dump --data-only --table=some_table some_db
```

I could further send this to a file by adding `> export.sql`

```
sudo docker exec <DOCKERNAME> pg_dump --data-only --table=some_table some_db > export.sql
```

Finally this works fine in an (interactive) ssh session.

However when using ssh the file is stored on remote host, instead of in my local system, I wish to get the file locally instead of in remote. I know I can send a command directly to the ssh shell and then exporting is done to the local host:

```
ssh -p 226 USER@HOST 'command' > local.sql
```

IE:

```
ssh -p 226 USER@HOST 'echo test' > local.sql
```

However on try to combine both commands I get an error

```
ssh -p 226 USER@HOST 'sudo docker exec <DOCKERNAME> pg_dump --data-only --table=some_table some_db' > local.sql


sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

And if I dare remove `sudo` (which would be silly) I get: `sh: docker: command not found`. How do I solve this? How can I export the pg dump direct to my local pc? With a simple command? Or at least without first creating a copy of the file on the remote system?

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid `sudo` or `docker exec` for this setup.

First, make sure that your database container has a port published to the host.  In Docker Compose, for example:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:11111:5432'
```

The second port number *must* be the ordinary PostgreSQL port 5432; the first port number can be anything that doesn't conflict; the `127.0.0.1` setting makes the published port only accessible on the local system.

Then, when you connect to the remote system, you can use ssh to set up a port forward:

```sh
ssh -L 22222:localhost:11111 -N me@remote.example.com
```

`ssh -L` sets up a port forward from your local system to the remote system; `ssh -N` says to not run a command, just do the port forward.

Now on your *local* system, you can run `psql` and other similar client tools.  Locally, `localhost:22222` connects to the ssh tunnel; that forwards to `localhost:11111` on the remote system; and that forwards to port 5432 in the container.

```sh
pg_dump --port=22222 --data-only --table=some_table some_db > export.sql
```

If you have the option of directly connecting to the database host, you could remove `127.0.0.1` from the `ports:` setting, and then `pg_dump --host=remote.example.com --port=11111`, without the `ssh` tunnel.  (But I'm guessing it's there for a reason.)

Comment: uh I cannot modify the postgres docker setup in any way - I really must use `docker exec` for this. Ssh tunnel is there since the postgres is only available from the remote server anyways, for other dockers. -- It's also because my local development pc doesn't have postgres binaries, they'd live in a (temporary) docker anyways during tests.

Answer (score 0):

You could forward socket connections over `ssh` then connect to the container from your host if you have `docker` installed:

```
ssh -n -N -T -L ${PWD}/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock user@host &
docker -H unix://${PWD}/docker.sock exec ...
```